# Could not build module <frameworkname>

Tags: xcode, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, cocoapods

I am building a React-Native iOS app and my app does not run. I'm not 100% sure but I think the problem might have started after I ran:

```
npm install @react-native-firebase/firestore 
cd ios
pod install
```

these all ran successfully but when I tried to run the app on the metro bundler simulator I get:

Command line invocation:

```
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace Eficio.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme Eficio -destination id=22A2358B-D28F-40E7-BB97-CE2E86056E94

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

Resolve Package Graph


Resolved source packages:
  leveldb: https://github.com/firebase/leveldb.git @ 1.22.4
  GTMSessionFetcher: https://github.com/google/gtm-session-fetcher.git @ 3.3.1
  GoogleAppMeasurement: https://github.com/google/GoogleAppMeasurement.git @ 10.22.1
  GoogleUtilities: https://github.com/google/GoogleUtilities.git @ 7.13.1
  GoogleDataTransport: https://github.com/google/GoogleDataTransport.git @ 9.4.0
  InteropForGoogle: https://github.com/google/interop-ios-for-google-sdks.git @ 100.0.0
  nanopb: https://github.com/firebase/nanopb.git @ 2.30910.0
  AppCheck: https://github.com/google/app-check.git @ 10.18.1
  SwiftProtobuf: https://github.com/apple/swift-protobuf.git @ 1.25.2
  Firebase: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk @ 10.22.1
  gRPC: https://github.com/google/grpc-binary.git @ 1.49.2
  Promises: https://github.com/google/promises.git @ 2.4.0
  abseil: https://github.com/google/abseil-cpp-binary.git @ 1.2022062300.1

Prepare packages

ComputeTargetDependencyGraph
note: Building targets in dependency order
note: Target dependency graph (138 targets)
    Target 'Eficio' in project 'Eficio'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Pods-Eficio' in project 'Pods' via file 'Pods_Eficio.framework' in build phase 'Link Binary'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'BVLinearGradient' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework BVLinearGradient' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-CoreModules' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework CoreModules' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'DoubleConversion' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework DoubleConversion' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'PromisesObjC' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework FBLPromises' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FirebaseAppCheckInterop' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework FirebaseAppCheckInterop' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FirebaseAuth' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework FirebaseAuth' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FirebaseCore' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework FirebaseCore' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FirebaseCoreExtension' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework FirebaseCoreExtension' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FirebaseCoreInternal' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework FirebaseCoreInternal' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FirebaseFirestore' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework FirebaseFirestore' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FirebaseFirestoreInternal' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework FirebaseFirestoreInternal' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FirebaseSharedSwift' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework FirebaseSharedSwift' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'GTMSessionFetcher' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework GTMSessionFetcher' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'GoogleUtilities' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework GoogleUtilities' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTAnimation' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RCTAnimation' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTBlob' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RCTBlob' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTFabric' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RCTFabric' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTImage' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RCTImage' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTLinking' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RCTLinking' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTNetwork' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RCTNetwork' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTSettings' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RCTSettings' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTText' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RCTText' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RCTTypeSafety' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RCTTypeSafety' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTVibration' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RCTVibration' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNCAsyncStorage' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RNCAsyncStorage' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNCMaskedView' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RNCMaskedView' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNDeviceInfo' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RNDeviceInfo' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNFBApp' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RNFBApp' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNFBAuth' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RNFBAuth' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNFBFirestore' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RNFBFirestore' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNGestureHandler' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RNGestureHandler' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNReanimated' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RNReanimated' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNSVG' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RNSVG' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNScreens' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework RNScreens' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-Core' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework React' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'ReactCommon' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework ReactCommon' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-Codegen' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework React_Codegen' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-Fabric' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework React_Fabric' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-FabricImage' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework React_FabricImage' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-ImageManager' in project 'Pods' via options '-framework React_ImageManager' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-Mapbuffer' in proj
```

The terminal hangs here and does not complete. I built the app on Xcode to see where the issues lie and this is what my Xcode shows:

[image]

I tried cleaning derived data, cleaning pod cache etc. None of the solutions I have tried seem to work.